# cosmosdb_account virtual_network_rule for_each

Tags: terraform, azure

I'm trying to create a set of subnet rules for a cosmosdb account.

I've tried a dynamic and a for_each on the resource and I get the same error each time - am I going about this the wrong way?

Currently trying this:

```
resource "azurerm_cosmosdb_account" "db" {
  name                = local.name
  location            = var.location
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name

  offer_type       = "Standard" #(Required) Specifies the Offer Type to use for this CosmosDB Account - currently this can only be set to Standard.
  enable_free_tier = var.enable_free_tier
  kind             = var.kind

  identity {
    type = "SystemAssigned"
  }

  ip_range_filter = join(",", local.network_rules.ip_rules)

  dynamic "virtual_network_rule" {
    for_each = var.virtual_network_subnet_ids
    content {
      id = each.value
    }
  }
}
```

Currently getting:

```
Error: each.value cannot be used in this context
│ 
│   on .terraform/modules/azurerm_cosmosdb_account/azurerm_cosmosdb_account/main.tf line 27, in resource "azurerm_cosmosdb_account" "db":
│   27:       id = each.value
│ 
│ A reference to "each.value" has been used in a context in which it
│ unavailable, such as when the configuration no longer contains the value in
│ its "for_each" expression. Remove this reference to each.value in your
│ configuration to work around this error.
╵
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A dynamic block does not use the `each` keyword, but the value of the `iterator` argument instead. If omitted, it will use the name of the dynamic block instead. Or as [the documentation](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/expressions/dynamic-blocks) states it:

> The `iterator` argument (optional) sets the name of a temporary variable that represents the current element of the complex value. If omitted, the name of the variable defaults to the label of the `dynamic` block.

It's generally fine to omit the iterator argument and just go with the (what should be a) unique name of the block. In your case, replace `each.value` with `virtual_network_rule.value`, so you get:

```
dynamic "virtual_network_rule" {
  for_each = var.virtual_network_subnet_ids

  content {
    id = virtual_network_rule.value
  }
}
```

If you do want to use the `iterator` argument, it would look something like this:

```
dynamic "virtual_network_rule" {
  for_each = var.virtual_network_subnet_ids
  iterator = "rule"

  content {
    id = rule.value
  }
}
```